# backup from web host, how to import email from folder in the backup

Tags: linux, email-server, outlook, export, import

Thank you for the interest in this topic, please help!

I made a backup from my hosting account at hostgator.com, but one of my friends that hosted their domain with me had IMAP setup in his outlook and now he "lost" all his emails when I moved providers.

I found the emails under the mail folder, as this:

mail > domain.com > name of the email > cur > bunch of files

which has a name structure like: 1598379680.M752525P860043.server.address.com,S=78175,W=79378/2,SZ

how in the nine hells do I import/transform those files to outlook?

Thank you,

Rom

Comment: That's `maildir` format. It's very common, it should be trivial to find tutorials on how to migrate it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have been trying several google searches like "maildir to eml convert python script" and others to no avail. Could you be kind enough to point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ChatGPT 4 I created this python script, I tested in python 3.9, as follows:

maildir_path = '/path_to_maildir/mail/domain.com/username_email/'
output_dir = '/path_to_maildir/mail/domain.com/username_email/eml/'

I hope it helps someone.

Rom

```
import mailbox
import os

# Adjust these paths for your setup
maildir_path = '/path/to/your/maildir'  # Path to your Maildir directory, terminate with "/"
output_dir = '/path/to/output/eml'  # Path to save the EML files, terminate with "/"

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# Open the Maildir mailbox
maildir = mailbox.Maildir(maildir_path, factory=None)

for key, message in maildir.iteritems():
    # Use the Maildir unique identifier in the EML filename
    sanitized_key = "".join(x for x in key if x.isalnum() or x in "._-")
    eml_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{sanitized_key}.eml')

    # Write the message to an EML file
    with open(eml_filename, 'wb') as eml_file:  # Correct variable name here
        eml_file.write(message.as_bytes())
    print(f'Converted {eml_filename}')

print('Done. Converted all emails to EML format.')
```

Comment: I hit a wall, the emails are encrypted with Dovecot. So I guess although I could convert, I have no clue how to find - or where to find - where the key is stored.